# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-axios' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-laravel-api\resources\js'

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am working in a crud with Laravel and Vue.js I have installed all dev devDependencies when I run NPM run watch me display this error as being:
[image]

In file app.js, I have included all dependencies:

```js
import "./bootstrap";
import vue from "vue";
window.Vue = vue;

import App from "./components/App.vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import axios from "axios";
import { routes } from "./routes";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: routes,
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router: router,
    render: (h) => h(App),
});
```

Can anyone help me with error above, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `axios` and `vue-axios` packages to package.json or did you install these packages? It looks you're not.
You need to install them with below;

```
npm i axios

npm i vue-axios
```